# Is there a way to query hardware sensors data on VMWare ESxi 5.5 without VSphere?

Tags: vmware-esxi

Is it possible to get hardware sensors data (especially temperature) querying directly via commandline or other way, and bypassing VSphere?

Comment: Maybe. It depends on what type of server you're using. Please provide those details.

Comment: Google for your Vendor-specific CIM providers

Comment: @Chopper3 _CIM_ has a very different meaning in my world...

Comment: @ewwhite - sector-specific term I believe ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments are correct. Your server vendor has to have a CIM or SNMP provider that reports on the hardware health - this could be a VMware driver package, or could be software independent and provided by a management card, like IPMI, iDRAC, or iLO.

So it depends on the server vendor's support for such things. If you have a desktop-class machine that you're using as a "server", you're likely out of luck.